# MultiValueDictKeyError Django CMS - Key 'language' not found in QueryDict

Tags: django, django-cms

My Django CMS site is suddenly unable to publish pages or add plugins due to the 'language' not present in the post.  I've never seen this issue before and I'm not sure how to fix it. The traceback is below.

Django version 1.4.5

Django CMS version 2.4.2

```
"Key 'language' not found in <QueryDict: {u'placeholder': [u'1434'], u'plugin_type': [u'TextPlugin']}>"

Request Method: POST
Request URL:  http://domain.com/admin/cms/page/495/add-plugin/
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:  
"Key 'language' not found in <QueryDict: {u'placeholder': [u'1434'], u'plugin_type': [u'TextPlugin']}>"
Exception Location: /var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 258
Python Executable:  /var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:  
['/var/www/domain.com/app',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/bin',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/src/django-admin-bootstrapped',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/src/johnny-panel',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib64/python2.6',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages']


 /var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py in add_plugin
            language = request.POST['language'] or get_language_from_request(request)
Local Vars

Variable  Value
parent  
None
self  
<cms.admin.pageadmin.PageAdmin object at 0x3b58710>
request 
"<WSGIRequest\npath:/admin/cms/page/495/add-plugin/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'placeholder': [u'1434'], u'plugin_type': [u'TextPlugin']}>,
 META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '39',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'YmXTWNblNRZix37nd5xINn6Eq0VciynN',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html, */*',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'djangocms_nodes_open=page_502; CMS_toolbar-collapsed=false;,
 'HTTP_HOST': 'domain.com',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://domain.com',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://domain.com/admin/cms/page/495/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.32 Safari/537.36',
 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN': 'YmXTWNblNRZix37nd5xINn6Eq0VciynN',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '64.21.121.50',
 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '64.21.121.50',
 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/admin/cms/page/495/add-plugin/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': '/admin/cms/page/495/add-plugin/',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '64.21.121.50',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '80',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'domain.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/0.17.2',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x210b980>,
 'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.glogging.LazyWriter object at 0x1b068d0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at 0x1bd3ef0>,
 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x21346d0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>"
parent_id 
None
placeholder_id  
u'1434'
placeholder 
<Placeholder: main-content>
page  
<cms.models.pagemodel.Page object at 0x4192210>
plugin_type 
u'TextPlugin'
/var/www/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__
            raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))
Local Vars

Variable  Value
self  
<QueryDict: {u'placeholder': [u'1434'], u'plugin_type': [u'TextPlugin']}>
key 
'language'
```

**UPDATE:**

Language settings straight from the python shell:

```
settings.LANGUAGES    
[('en', 'English')]

settings.LANGUAGE_CODE    
'en'

settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'    

settings.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE    
0

settings.USE_I18N    
False

settings.USE_L10N    
False
```

Comment: Can you update the question with your `settings.py` and explain what you mean by "I think it's related to a single language django app."

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I updated with relevant language settings (settings.py is huge).  The comment about single language was just a hunch based on issues that seem related in Google search results, but I have no real basis.  I removed it so it doesn't distract from the real issue.

Comment: Umm, `settings.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE`, why is this `0`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's because it should be.  It's the index of the languages array.  You can see an example from ojii here https://gist.github.com/ojii/776313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with django cms that throws an error when 'languages' is not present in the POST data; a MultiValueDictKeyError error.

As of this writing, there is an open pull request for a fix from @blackrobot. https://github.com/divio/django-cms/pull/2151

If you need the fix before it's integrated into the master branch and released, you can fork this pull or edit your local copy. Edit line 1130 of

```
cms/admin/pageadmin.py
```

to become

```
language = request.POST.get('language') or get_language_from_request(request)
```